# Managing mysql users in a Docker environment

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, containers

## My goal is to create the following:

- **one nginx container** as a single entry point which will load balance amongst N node containers (APIs).
- **one MySQL container** (ultimately I will run replicas as well, not sure if this is related the problem).
- **many API containers** that will connect to the mysql container

Based on my understanding: normally there should exist a user with specific access to specific tables with a specific host for each server which connects to the mysql instance.

## The problem:

How can I maintain the same level of security while allowing n node containers to dynamically enter/leave load balancing.

## my attempts at solving this:

- force all node containers to spawn within a specific ip range, and create an api user which accepts connections from that ip range. I'm not sure if I can force docker to create containers within a specific ip range. Also, this solution still lowers the security as now there is a range available instead of 1-1.
- If I can find a way to create private connections between containers (I know --link does this but it does not dynamically update on reboots) then I wouldn't have to expose the DB publicly at all. In this case would it be acceptable to have an API user with host % since I am assured that no one can connect to that container other than my own containers?

Comment: are you deploying on docker swarm or anything similar?

Comment: I eventually plan to use Kubernetes, though if swarm helps me solve this problem I`m not against adopting it over fleet/kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running all containers inside one node you can expose all API and DB containers on localhost interface. This way they won't be accessible outside of node and visible for each other. If you want to deploy this in some kind of cloud based on Kubernetes you must ensure that your network meets minimum requirements as stated in: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/networking.md which means that all nodes can communicate with each other freely. But even then you can secure your deployment using i.e. firewall rules or providing private network only for internal communication. When you have secure network you should not be afraid of foreign connections.